# New hdd not detected in BIOS after CloneZilla

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, clone, clonezilla

I did a disk to disk clone with clonezilla. I cloned all partitions and used the `-k1` option. I put the new hdd in and it doesn't boot. BIOS does not detect an hdd. Why might that be?

old hdd: 80gb, new: 500gb. both hitachi. both 2.5" sata.
the old hdd was detected in BIOS before the clone

Update:
I'm looking at the hdd in windows computer management and the partitioning goes:
1. 530MB EISA Configuration
2. System Reserved 100MB NTFS
3. H: 465GB NTFS
4. 10MB Unallocated

Update:
I got the drive to be detected. It was a connectivity issue as it was in the slot as opposed to usb like before. The new hdd is slightly smaller than the old so I added some paper to make it thicker.
However, now windows won't boot. Seeing what fixmbr can do.

Update:
I burnt a win7 repair cd and used it with the new hdd installed. It found and repaired errors, restarted. Now the os boots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an hdd slot in your laptop. Small size differences in the hdd can cause connectivity problems.

Also, using CloneZilla on an hdd that boots windows 7 may require a win7 repair cd to correct inconsistencies in the MBR